# Singular value decomposition in the language of operator theory

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory, svd

Let $H_i$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space, $A\in\mathfrak L(H_1,H_2)$ be compact, $|A|:=\sqrt{A^\ast A}$ and $\sigma\in\mathbb R$.

> How would we describe the singular value decomposition of $A$ in the language of operator theory? (Assuming $\dim H_i\in\mathbb N$, if necessary.)

To fix terminology, say that $\sigma>0$ is a *singular value* of $A$ if $\sigma$ is an eigenvalue of $|A|$, i.e. $\mathcal N(\sigma-|A|)\ne\{0\}$. This definition is equivalent to claim that there are $x_i\in H_i$ with $\left\|x_i\right\|_{H_i}=1$ and $$Ax_1\sigma x_2\text{ and }A^\ast x_2=\sigma x_1\tag1.$$

By the [Courant-Rayleigh minimax principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant_minimax_principle), we may enumerate the singular values of $A$ in nonincreasing order. So, let $\sigma_i(A)$ denote the $i$th largest singular value of $A$ for $i\in\mathbb N$. (If there are only $k$ different singular values, $\sigma_i(A)=0$ for all $i>k$.)

Now we may mimic some parts of the spectral theorem for compact self-adjoint operators: Let \begin{align}E_i&:=\mathcal N(\sigma_i(A)-|A|),\\d_i&:=\dim E_i\end{align} and $\left(e^{(i)}_1,\ldots,e^{(i)}_{d_i}\right)$ be an orthonormal basis of $E_i$ for $i\in\mathbb N$ and \begin{align}(\sigma_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}:=(\underbrace{\sigma_1(A),\ldots,\sigma_1(A)}_{=:\:d_1\text{ times}},\underbrace{\sigma_2(A),\ldots,\sigma_2(A)}_{=:\:d_2\text{ times}},\ldots),\\(e_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}:=\left(e^{(1)}_1,\ldots,e^{(1)}_{d_1},e^{(2)}_1,\ldots,e^{(2)}_{d_2},\ldots\right).\end{align} Then $(e_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal N(A)^\perp$ (since $\mathcal N(A)=\mathcal N(|A|)$) and $$|A|x_1=\sum_{i\in\mathbb N}\sigma_i\langle x_1,e_i\rangle_{H_1}e_i\tag2.$$

> How do we need to proceed? And how is this related to the polar decomposition$^1$ of $A$?

---

$^1$ There is an unique partial isometry $U$ from $H_1$ to $H_2$ with $\mathcal N(U)=\mathcal N(A)$ and $A=U|A|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The singular value decomposition is obtained from the polar decomposition, together with the spectral theorem.

The polar decomposition gives you $A=V|A|$, where $V$ is a partial isometry such that $\operatorname{ran}V^*V=\overline{\operatorname{ran}A^*}$, and $|A|=(A^*A)^{1/2}$. Since $|A|\in B(H_1)$ and positive and compact, we apply the Spectral Theorem to obtain 
$$\tag1
|A|=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sigma_j\,P_j,
$$
where $\sigma_1\geq\sigma_2\geq\cdots\geq0$ and each $P_j$ is a rank-one projection. We can rewrite $(1)$ as 
$$\tag2
|A|=U^*DU,
$$
where $U$ is a unitary and the is the diagonal operator (in the canonical basis, say) with diagonal $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots$

Then
$$\tag3
A=VU^*DU=WDU
$$
where $D$ is as above, $W$ is a partial isometry, and $U$ is unitary.

An often more useful way of writing this is choosing unit vectors $e_j$ with $P_je_j=e_j$ (so they form an orthonormal basis of the range of $|A|$) and write $(1)$ as 
$$\tag4
|A|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sigma_k\,\langle\cdot,e_k\rangle \,e_k. 
$$
Then
$$\tag5
A=V|A|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sigma_k\,\langle\cdot,e_k\rangle \,Ve_k. 
$$
As $V$ is an isometry on $\operatorname{ran}|A|$, we get that $\{Ve_k\}$ is orthonormal. So the Singular Value Decomposition can be restated as saying

> If $A\in L(H_1,H_2)$ is compact there exist orthonormal families $\{e_k\}\subset H_1$ and $\{f_k\}\subset H_2$ such that 
>   $$\tag6
> A=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sigma_k\,\langle\cdot,e_k\rangle \,f_k.
> $$

Comment: As I read your answer, I've remembered that I already knew the answer some time ago. The funny thing is that I've answered a [related question asked by you](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/208508/47771) ... I'm hopping between too many disciplines recently; repeatedly forgetting things I already knew.

Comment: BTW, is there an established naming for the operators $A^\ast A$ and $|A|$?

Comment: Not super standard, but it is common to say that $|A|$ is the absolute value of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. Oh, and please note that something went wrong in your identity $V^*V=\overline{\operatorname{ran}A^*}$. We've clearly got $\mathcal N(V)=\mathcal N(A)$ and hence $\overline{\mathcal R(A^\ast)}=\mathcal N(V)^\perp$.

Comment: Everything in your post is clear to me. Especially the "more useful" form. But I fail to see how we construct the unitary operator $U$. I've asked for that separately: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3657914/47771.

Comment: And there is another subtlety: You say the $e_j$ form an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal R(|A|)$, but I think they actually even form an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal N(A)^\perp=\mathcal N(|A|)^\perp=\overline{\mathcal R(|A|)}$. (And note that $\mathcal R(|A|)$ doesn't need to be closed; hence not be Hilbert space itself.) Beyond that, I'm a bit struggling to answer the question whether $\operatorname{rank}|A|=\operatorname{rank}A$. It is surely true when $H_2$ is finite dimensional (since then $\overline{\mathcal R(|A|)}=\mathcal R(|A|)$).

Comment: Your first question: $\mathcal N(V)^\perp=\mathcal N(V^*V)^\perp=\mathcal R(V^*V)$, so $V^*V$ is the projection onto $\overline{\mathcal R(A^*)}$.

Comment: Second question: it's a basis for the range of $|A|$: you can see it explicitly in $(4)$. And as $V$ is an isometry on the range of $|A|$ it preserves dimension, so the rank is the same.

Comment: First question: What I meant was that your identity doesn't make sense, since the left-hand side is an operator, while the right-hand side is a space.

Comment: Second question: There seems to be something I'm missing. I've read that the orthonormal basis $(e_i)$ from the spectral theorem (which is only an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal R(|A|)$ as you say) can be supplemented to an orthonormal basis of $H_1$ by an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal N(|A|)$. How is this possible? I thought this would be an application of $H_1=\mathcal N(|A|)\oplus\mathcal N(|A|)^\perp$, but if $(e_i)$ is not an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal N(|A|)^\perp$, I don't get why this should hold.

Comment: Yes, one can make the distinction. It doesn't give you any information, though: a projection identifies naturally with its range.

Comment: Yes, you have $\{e_j\}^\perp=R(|A|)^\perp=\ker |A|$. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: What are you denoting by $\{e_j\}^\perp$? My problem is that $H_1=M\oplus M^\perp$ only holds for closed subspaces $M$. If $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal R(|A|)$, how do you express an element of $\overline{\mathcal R(|A|)}\setminus\mathcal R(|A|)$ only with $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ and an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal N(|A|)$?

Comment: The orthogonal of a set is the set of those elements orthogonal to each element of the set; you've been using this notation all the time. As for your other questions, how is an "orthonormal basis of $M$" different from an "orthonormal basis of $\overline M$"?

Comment: Is this a question or are you saying that an orthonormal basis of $M$ is automatically an orthonormal basis of $\overline M$? I call $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ an orthonormal basis of a subset $M$ of a Hilbert space $H$ if $x=\sum_{i\in I}\langle x,e_i\rangle_He_i$ for all $x\in M$.

Comment: Yes. And what would an orthonormal basis for $\overline M$ be? If you can enlarge the basis, you would get that $M$ is not dense in $\overline M$.

Comment: Now you're confusing me. You say that if $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ is an orthonormal basis of $M$, then it must also be an orthonormal basis of $\overline M$? But this is precisely what I said initially for $M=\mathcal R(|A|)$, isn't it? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I feel a bit stupid, since you have definitely more knowledge than me, but I really don't get it. Also struggle to see what you wrote about $\operatorname{rank}|A|$. You say that $V$ is an isometry on $\mathcal R(A)$, but I would say it is even an isometry $\overline{\mathcal R(A)}$. However, from the fact it is an isometry on $\mathcal R(A)$ we can infer that $\operatorname{rank}|A|=\dim\mathcal R(|A|)=\dim U\mathcal R(|A|)$ and now I guess we just need to notice that $U\mathcal R(|A|)=\mathcal R(U|A|)=\mathcal R(A)$.

Comment: In any case, I think you can strengthen your conclusion in your answer: $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ are not arbitrary orthonormal families of $H_1$ and $H_2$, respectively. They are orthonormal bases of $\mathcal R(|A|)$ and $\mathcal R(A)$, respectively. In particular, they have the same dimension. It would be great if you could fill the gaps which are still open in my last two comments. Even if it seems to be obvious for you.

Comment: At this stage, I don't know what you understand and what you don't. Talking about an orthonormal basis of a non-closed space makes little sense. Like saying that $\{e^{2\pi i k t}\}_k$ is an orthonormal basis of $C[0,1]$ inside $L^2[0,1]$; it's already a basis of $L^2[0,1]$, so making the distinction is kind of pointless.  That they are orthonormal bases of $\overline{\mathcal R(|A|)}$ and $\overline{\mathcal R(A)}$ respectively, follows directly from $(6)$; so I have no idea what gaps you are talking about.

Comment: Then we simply got a major misunderstanding. That the $\{e_j\}$ are an orthonormal basis of $\overline{\mathcal R(|A|)}$ was what I wrote initially and I felt like you've corrected me that they are only an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal R(|A|)$ in your third comment.

Comment: I don't know what correction you refer to. But, more importantly, what difference could it possibly make? Again: an orthonormal basis cannot be "only" the orthonormal basis of a non-closed subspace. An orthonormal basis of a subspace is an orthogonal set of vectors that is maximally orthogonal in the subspace. If it is maximal orthogonal in a subspace, it is maximal orthogonal in the closure; so the distinction you are trying to make is absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, you're right. And that was why I was so confused by your correction. But I guess you didn't try to correct me and I just understood your comment totally wrong.

Comment: I cannot comment/edit/delete the "correction" because I don't know what it is.

Comment: How did you obtain that $W=VU^\ast$ is a partial isometry? And what are $\mathcal N(W)$ and $\mathcal R(W)$? Clearly, $U$ is unitary and hence bijective. $V$ is a partial isometry with $\mathcal N(V)=\mathcal N(A)=\mathcal N(|A|)$ and $\mathcal N(V)=\{x\in H_1:U^\ast x\in\mathcal N(V)\}$ ...

Comment: Since $U$ is a unitary, $W^*W=UV^*VU^*$, which is a projection; that's enough to imply that $W$ is a partial isometry. The equality $(3)$ tells you that $R(A)\subset R(W)$. Also, $WW^*=VU^*UV^*=VV^*$, so R(W)=R(V)$.

Comment: Thanks. It's clear to me that $W^\ast W$ is an orthogonal projection and hence $W$ is a partial isometry. $\mathcal R(A)\subseteq\mathcal R(W)$ is trivial from the definition. But how did you conclude $\mathcal R(W)=\mathcal R(V)$ from $WW^\ast=VV^\ast$?

Comment: As $W$ is a partial isometry, the projection $WW^*$ is the projection onto $R(W)$.

Comment: Can we alter the definition of $W$ and $D$ so that $W$ is an orthogonal operator on $H_2$? I've asked this question for the finite-dimensional case here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3656131/47771. But I'd be interested in the general case as well.

Comment: I don't think so. If $A$ is a weighted unilateral shift, then $U=I$ and $W$ is the unilateral shift.

Comment: I'm not sure why this example shows that the desired construction is not possible. Maybe you've got my intent wrong? I'd like to have a result like Theorem 1.1 here: https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2014/other/linalg_INFK/svdneu.pdf.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I answered. If, in your notation, $$A=\sum_n\frac1n\,e_{n+1}\otimes e_n,$$ then $A$ **cannot** be written as $WDV$ with $D$ diagonal and $W,V$ unitaries.

Comment: I see ... So, this is only possible in the finite-dimensional case, right?

Comment: Yes, in finite-dimension you can do the polar decomposition with a unitary.

Comment: I'm wondering whether the SVD is uniquely characterized by assuming that $W$ is a partial isometry: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3693892/47771. I'm not sure whether this a general property of partial isometries, but at least the specific one you've constructed in your answer has "$|I|$ orthogonal columns": Since $V^\ast V$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\overline{\mathcal R(|A|)}$ and $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ is an ONB of this space, $$\langle f_m,f_n\rangle_{H_2}=\begin{cases}\delta_{mn}&\text{, if }m,n\in I\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ for all $m,n\in N_1=\mathbb N\cap[1,\dim H_1]$.

Comment: From this we obtain $$W^\ast W=\sum_{i\in I}\tilde e_i\otimes e_i$$ (sum in the SOT), where $(\tilde e_n)_{n\in N_1}$ is an arbitrary ONB of $H_1$ we have chosen such that $D=\sum_{i\in I}\sigma_i\tilde e_i\otimes\tilde e_i$, and $$WW^\ast=\sum_{n\in N_1}f_n\otimes f_n.$$ What I'm trying to achieve is to see why $A^\ast A=U^\ast DW^\ast WDU=U^\ast D^2U$ (i.e. why the $W^\ast W$ can be removed).