# If $(U,\Sigma,V)$ is a singular value decomposition of $A$, do the first $\text{rank}A$ columns of $V$ and $U$ form orthonormal bases?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Let

- $m,n\in\mathbb N$
- $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $|A|:=\sqrt{A^TA}$
- $r:=\operatorname{rank}A$
- $\sigma_1>\cdots>\sigma_r>\sigma_{r+1}=\cdots=\sigma_n=0$ denote the singular values of $A$

We say that $(U,\Sigma,V)$ is a singular value decomposition of $A$ if

1. $U\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ is a partial isometry;
2. $\Sigma=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$;
3. $V\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is orthogonal

and $$A=U\Sigma V^T\tag1.$$

> Can we show that
>
> 1. The first $r$ columns $(e_1,\ldots,e_r)$ and $(f_1,\ldots,f_r)$ of $V$ and $U$ are orthonormal bases of $\mathcal R(|A|)$ and $\mathcal R(A)$, respectively?
> 2. $\mathcal N(U)=\mathcal N(A)$ (noting that $\mathcal N(A)=\mathcal N(|A|)$)?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @user251257 The claims are clear to me when $(U,\Sigma,V)$ is constructed by the polar decomposition and spectral theorem. I'm now trying to figure out whether they hold for any $(U,\Sigma,V)$ with the given assumptions in the questions. It's clear to me that the columns of $V$ are an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$ (since they are orthonormal).

Comment: Hint: let $y=Ax$ then $y = U\Sigma V^T x= \sum_{i=1}^r u_i \sigma_i v_i^T x$.

Comment: @user251257 I don't see why $\sigma_i$ pops up in your equation. We've got $A^TA=V\Sigma U^TU\Sigma V^T$. The question is: Why can we remove the $U^TU$? We know that it is an orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal N(U)^\perp$.

Comment: $U^TU$ is the identity, as $U$ is orthogonal by assumption. But I only used $A$ not $A^TA$.

Comment: @user251257 (a) $U$ is *not* orthogonal by assumption. The assumption is that it is a partial isometry (i.e. an isometry on $\mathcal N(U)^\perp$) which is equivalent to saying that $U^TU$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal N(U)^\perp$. But this might be enough as long as we can show that $\mathcal R(\Sigma V^T)\subseteq\mathcal N(U)^\perp$. (b) I came up with $A^TA$ since the singular values are the eigenvalues of $|A|:=\sqrt{A^TA}$. So, I've considered $A^TA$ to see why the $\sigma_i$'s pop up in your equation.

Comment: you assume $A=U\Sigma V^T$. If you compute $U\Sigma V^T x$ for some $x$, you will get the sum. That is just matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$\tag1 AA^*=U\Sigma^2 U^*.$$ Taking the trace in $(1)$, 
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma^2)=\operatorname{Tr}(AA^*)=\operatorname{Tr}(U\Sigma^2U^*)=\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma^2 U^*U). 
$$
Then
$$
0=\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma^2\,(I-U^*U))=\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma\,(I-U^*U)^2\,\Sigma)
$$
As the trace is faithful, we get $\Sigma(I-U^*U)^2\Sigma=0$, and so $(I-U^*U)\Sigma=0$. So $$\tag2
\Sigma=U^*U\Sigma=\Sigma\,U^*U.
$$
Now
$$
A^*A=V\Sigma U^*U\Sigma V^*=V\Sigma^2\,V^*. 
$$
Now
$$
\ker A=\ker A^*A=\ker V\Sigma^2 V^*=\ker \Sigma V^*.
$$
So, taking orthogonals,
$$
\operatorname{ran} A^*=\operatorname{ran}V\Sigma.
$$
This shows that the first $r$ columns of $V$ span the range of $A^*$ (which is the same as the range of $|A|$). Going back to $(1)$, 
$$
\ker A^*=\ker AA^*=\ker U\Sigma^2\,U^*=\ker \Sigma U^*,
$$
so 
$$
\operatorname{ran} A=\operatorname{ran} U\Sigma,
$$
so the first $r$ columns of $U$ span the range of $A$.

It is not true in general that $\ker A=\ker U$. For instance take 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix} \,\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} \,\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}. 
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How did you remove $U^\ast U$ in $A^*A=V\Sigma U^*U\Sigma V^*=V\Sigma^2\,V^*$?

Comment: I proved it. That's what the answer is about.

Comment: Wait a second. Is there anything you've used here which wouldn't work in the same way for the same objects in the context of the infinite-dimensional scenario of the other question?

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is trace class, I would think it should work. With a few closures of ranges thrown in.

Comment: Hm, $\Sigma$ being trace-class is equivalent to $A$ being trace-class isn't it?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Coming back to my first comment: I guess what's worrying me is how you've obtained $\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma^2)=\operatorname{Tr}(AA^*)$.

Comment: I didn't obtain that, you gave it in your hypotheses, when you said that the diagonal of $\Sigma$ were the singular values of $A$.

Comment: Well, yes. The crucial thing is that the trace doesn't depend on the choice of the onb. So, indeed, it follows by that hypotheses.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the trace is faithful". What does *faithful* mean here? It seems like you mean that $\operatorname{tr}L=0\Rightarrow L=0$, but that's obviously wrong. Instead, my argument would be that $$0=\operatorname{tr}\Sigma(I_n-U^\ast U)^2\Sigma)=\left\|(I_n-U^\ast U)\Sigma\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}}^2$$ from which we can conclude that $0=(I_n-U^\ast U)\Sigma$. A second thing I don't understand in your approach is how you would conclude the latter from $\Sigma(I_n-U^\ast U)^2\Sigma=0$ (unless each $\sigma_i>0$).

Comment: "Faithful" is a standard term that means "injective on positive operators". If $L\geq0$ and $\operatorname{Tr}(L)=0$, then $L=0$. And, since $P=I=U^*U$ is  a projection and $\Sigma\geq0$, $$0=\Sigma P^2\Sigma=(P\Sigma)^*(P\Sigma). $$ For any operator $T$, the equality $T^*T=0$ implies $T=0$.

Comment: Yes, I see. If $L\ge0$, then $|L|=L$ and we know that the nuclear norm is equal to $\operatorname{tr}|L|$. And in the second part, I guess you've intended to write $P=I-U^\ast U$ instread.

Comment: The fact that the trace is faithful doesn't require any theory nor norms. If $\operatorname{Tr}(T^*T)=0$, take any $x$ of norm one, extend it to an orthonormal basis; then (writing the trace in that basis) $0=\operatorname{Tr}(T^*T)=\|Tx\|^2+\text{nonnegative stuff}\geq\|Tx\|^2$, so $Tx=0$. And yes, there was a typo in the comment.

Comment: How did you obtain $\ker V\Sigma^2 V^*=\ker \Sigma V$? Since $V\Sigma^2 V^*=V\Sigma(V\Sigma)^\ast$, I obtain $\ker V\Sigma^2 V^\ast=\ker\Sigma V^\ast$ instead.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.

Comment: Is there something which implies that the first $r$ columns of $U$ are orthogonal?

Comment: I mean, generally, if $U\in\mathfrak L(H_1,H_2)$ is a partial isometry, then $U^\ast U$ is a projection and hence $$U^\ast U\left(\operatorname{id}_{H_1}-U^\ast U\right)=0.$$ Can we infer that $U$ is left-orthogonal, i.e. $U^\ast U=\operatorname{id}_{H_1}$?

Comment: No, a partial isometry could even have equal columns.

Comment: Then I guess we could have conclude more than $U$ being a partial isometry in your construction in the other question (where you've defined $U$ to be $WV$, where $W$ is the partial isometry from the polar decomposition). Is at least this particular $U$ left-orthogonal?

Comment: Now I don't know if you are talking finite dimension (this question) or infinite dimension (the other one).

Comment: For the moment I'm considering the finite-dimensional case, but the explicit construction of $(U,\Sigma,V)$ you gave in the other question. You've shown that the $U$ there (you've called it $W$) is a partial isometry, which is what I've assumed here. However, your construction made use of the polar decomposition $A=W|A|$ (your symbol for this $W$ was $V$). In fact, you've defined $U:=WV$ from which we saw that $U$ is a partial isometry satisfying $U\Sigma V^\ast=A$. However, I think we should define $U$ differently. The important thing is the following: Say $|A|=\sum_{i=1}^r\sigma_ie_i⊗e_i$

Comment: and extend $(e_1,…,e_r)$ to an onb $(e_1,…,e_n)$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Let $(\tilde e_1,…,\tilde e_n)$ be any basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\Sigma:=\sum_{i=1}^r\sigma_i\tilde e_i\otimes\tilde e_i$, $V:=\sum_{i=1}^n\tilde e_i\otimes e_i$. Since $W$ is a partial isometry, $$f_i:=We_i\;\;\;\text{for }i\in\{1,…,r\}$$ is an onb of $W\mathcal N(W)^\perp=\mathcal R(A)$. Extend $(f_1,…,f_r)$ to an onb $(f_1,…,f_m)$ of $\mathbb R^m$. Now define $$U:=\sum_{i=1}^{\min(m,\:n)}\tilde e_i\otimes f_i.$$

Comment: Then we've still got $$A=W|A|=WV\Sigma V^\ast=\sum_{i=1}^r\sigma e_i\otimes f_i=U\Sigma V^\ast$$. Moreover, $$U^\ast U=\sum_{i=1}^{\min(m,\:n)}\tilde e_i\otimes\tilde e_i.$$ So, $U$ has $\min(m,n)$ orthogonal columns and, if $n\le m$, it is left-orthogonal. What do you think? I don't know whether there is a particular name for such an $U$, but I think this property is what we should assume $U$ in the SVD to admit.

Comment: I'll read what you wrote a bit later.

Comment: Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you did is not wrong, but it doesn't contribute much (sorry). First, you don't need your $V$, since you already wrote $|A|$ in diagonal form; the point of $V$ is to diagonalize $|A|$; what that means, is that you can take $\bar e_j=e_j$ in your argument and $V=I$. The usual $V$ in the singular value decomposition would be the unitary that takes the canonical basis to your $\{e_j\}$. So your $U$ is simply $W$: the partial isometry in the polar decomposition is unique one prescribes that the partial isometry maps ran$(|A|)$ to ran$(A)$. *(continued)*

Comment: You may want to check when you say "orthogonal columns". It doesn't work like that when you don't have a unitary. For instance $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ has "orthogonal columns" in the canonical basis; but with a change of basis this is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1/2&1/2&0\\1/2&1/2&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}. $$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The idea is that the $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is the onb of eigenvectors of $|A|$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ and $(\tilde e_1,\ldots,\tilde e_n)$ is any onb of $\mathbb R^n$ we want to express the diagonal form of $A$. So, for example, $(\tilde e_1,\ldots,\tilde e_n)$ being the standard basis so that $\Sigma=\text{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)$. Regarding the partial isometry in the polar decomposition: The crucial point should be that only its values on $\mathcal N(W)^\perp$ contribute in the expression $A=(WV)\Sigma V^\ast$,

Comment: which is why we can discard its values on $\mathcal N(W)$. That's what I've done in my definition of $U$. I'm not sure what you mean in your comment regarding the orthogonal columns. What I've meant was that that the "columns" $(f_1,\ldots,f_{m\wedge n})$ of $U$ are orthonormal or, assuming $(\tilde e_1,\ldots,\tilde e_n)$ is the standard basis, $\text{col}_1U,\ldots,\text{col}_{m\wedge n}$ are orthonormal. Anything wrong with that?